# Вывод более одной переменной при помощи bot.send_message() aiogram

Tags: python, бот, aiogram

Пишу тг бота, возникла серьезная проблема. Мой вопрос прост: как отправить юзеру не одну, а несколько переменных при помощи bot.send_message()? Смущает именно синтаксис. Я попытался реализовать вывод данных из словаря так:

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Фамилия: %s' % vlnt_data['surname'] ' Имя: %s' % vlnt_data['name'])
```

Выводит трейсбэк: неправильный синтаксис. Пожалуйста, помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбирайте вариант. Все делают одно и то же:

```
vlnt_data = {'surname': 'Иванов', 'name': 'Иван'}

print('Фамилия: %s' % vlnt_data['surname'] + ' Имя: %s' % vlnt_data['name'])
print('Фамилия: %s Имя: %s' % (vlnt_data['surname'], vlnt_data['name']))
print('Фамилия: {} Имя: {}'.format(vlnt_data['surname'], vlnt_data['name']))
print(f"Фамилия: {vlnt_data['surname']} Имя: {vlnt_data['name']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Фамилия: %s' % vlnt_data['surname'] + ' Имя: %s' % vlnt_data['name'])
```